# how to return the data after getting response in http api call in angular 4?

Tags: angular, api, http, subscribe

> This is my function which i define in my service and i am calling this
>   service method in my component but it return before the response has
>   come from http api call, so i get undefined return data.

```
    home(){
       this._http
      .post("http://localhost:3000/home", {
      email: JSON.parse(this.cookieService.get("token")).email
    })
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.result = JSON.parse(data["_body"]);
     console.log(this.result); 
     send=>{return this.result}
    })
  }
```

Comment: how are you calling this method from your component? can you share both conponent and service code?

Comment: this.result=this.chatService.home();

Comment: result in my component variable where i want to store return data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the observable from your service like the following,

```
home() : Observable<any> { 
    return this._http
      .post("http://localhost:3000/home", {
          email: JSON.parse(this.cookieService.get("token")).email
      })
     .map(data => {
        let result = JSON.parse(data["_body"]);
        return result;
     });
}
```

And subscribe on the returned `Observable` from you component code like this,

```
this.chatService.home().subscribe((result) => { this.result = result; });
```

Comment: i get this error on using ur code ERROR in /Users/shubhamkumar/Sites/public_html/my-app/src/app/body/home/Home.component.ts (49,31): Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'

Comment: make the service return  `Observable<any>`. see the edited code

Answer (score 0):

Your service function will be as below :

```
home() {
  return this._http.post("http://localhost:3000/home", {
    email: JSON.parse(this.cookieService.get("token")).email
  }).map((res:Response) => res.json());
}
```

then in your component you need to subscribe that service so that API call is made and you can store result in your component variable.

```
//Component code

componentFunction() {
  this.chatService.home().subscribe(data => {
    this.result = JSON.parse(data["_body"]);
    console.log(this.result);
  });
}
```

Comment: this solve my problem but how to assign the data in my variable "result" in service

Comment: you can not assign that value in your service as we have subscribed in component.

Answer (score 0):

the "angular way" is that the service return a Observable. It's the component which subscribe to the service in an OnInit

```
//Your service
home(){
       return this._http  //<--return the http.post
      .post("http://localhost:3000/home", {
      email: JSON.parse(this.cookieService.get("token")).email
    }).map((res:Response) => res.json())

//Your component
    constructor(private myService:Service)
    //Normally in onOnInit
    ngOnInit()
    {
     this.myService.subscribe(data => {
        this.result=data;
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comment you did

```
this.result=this.chatService.home();
```

In your service, you do

```
.subscribe(data => {
  this.result = JSON.parse(data["_body"]);
 console.log(this.result); 
 send=>{return this.result}
})
```

**You're all doing it wrong**.

When you make asynchronous HTTP calls, you need to **assign values IN the subscribe**. Since you call it in your component, you should instead do

```
this.result=this.chatService.home()
  .subscribe(data => this.result = data);
```

In your service, you get this

```
home(){
 this._http
   .post("http://localhost:3000/home", {
     email: JSON.parse(this.cookieService.get("token")).email
   })
   .map(res => res.json())
```

What happens is that **you move the subscribe logic to your component**. You also need to use the `map` operator, because from what I've seen, you're dealing with JSON here : `this.result = JSON.parse(data["_body"]);`. Well, Angular Response objects have a `json()` method thought just for that purpose !